# Can I have help to solve a Git phantom directory which is in lowercase?

Tags: git

Our git repository is having problems with one file appearing out of nowhere, preventing checkout and overwriting existing changes if its committed.

I believe its because somebody renamed a /reg folder to /Reg outside of git, and now whenever we make changes to a file in /Reg git thinks there are two files being changed.

In git it looks like this - http://prntscr.com/kg4asc

I have found from research that a fix is to move /reg into /Reg but if i try to do this i get a `fatal: cannot move directory over file` error.

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the output of `git status`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found out how to fix it...

`git mv reg tmpreg`
followed by 
`git mv tmpreg Reg`

This basically tricks git into thinking you have renamed the folder.

Comment: Glad you found the solution, although a "trick" probably isn't what it is.